# generate docx file got from server through jsp error

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, websphere

I'm trying to return an docx file which i got from server by using jsp

```
if(pathfile != null){
        String mimetype=application.getMimeType(pathfile);
        System.out.println("mimeType: "+ mimetype);
        response.setContentType("application/ms-word");     
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Resultfile.docx");

        File file = new File(pathfile);
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
        //OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();

        int i;   
        while ((i=fileIn.read()) != -1) {  
        out.write(i);   
      }   
      fileIn.close(); 

    }else{

        %> <div>Khong co file</div> <%

    }
```

but when i try to open the file, the MSW announced me this 
[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Occ3K.png)
[error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLRYc.png)

i still can read the content after clicking okay but i don't know what is the problem, how can i fix that ?
i'm using word 2016 and the server is websphere V9

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
response.setContentType("application/ms-word");
```

Use

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
```

because your file type is doc**x**.

Refer microsoft documentation **[here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/05/08/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2/)**.